# Trigger google.script.run.withFailureHandler from Code.gs

Tags: google-apps-script

Calling a 'server-side' function in Google App Script can be achieved with:

```
google.script.run.withFailureHandler(CallbackFailure)
      .withSuccessHandler(CallbackSuccess).doSomething();
```

In `Code.gs`, how can I ensure `CallbackFailure` is called? I attempted:

```
function doSomething() {
   throw new Error( "Trigger CallbackFailure" );
}
```

However I receive an error because of an unhandled exception. I had hoped throwing an `Error` would call `CallbackFailure` - but it was just guess work and doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see any problem in your code, it should work fine.

I did in my **index.html**

```
google.script.run.withFailureHandler(function(e){console.log("failure handler",e)})
    .withSuccessHandler(function(e){console.log("success handler",e)}).doSomething();
```

and in my **code.gs**

```
function doSomething() {
   throw new Error( "Trigger CallbackFailure" );
}
```

and my browser console logged:

> failure handler Error {name: "", message: "Error: Trigger CallbackFailure"}

`withFailureHandler` callback function is called if the server-side function throws an exception as stated in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withfailurehandlerfunction). This worked fine.

Maybe there could be some other issue in your script, you can share your container bound script if you like.